# Custom Ternary-esque Operator for Enumerations with Custom Compiler

Tags: c#, asp.net, enumeration, ternary-operator

I recently found my self wondering if there was an existing operator similar to the Ternary Operator, but for enumerations....  This could be a handle tool for writing less code for processing the value of an enumeration...

I was unable to find anything, so I pose the question...

How can I build my own operator for handling enumerations as outlined below?

Take the following enumeration:

```
public enum ComTypes { Call, Email, SMS }
```

Lets say I need to assign a title of a popup dialog based on the ComType.  Currently I could use Ternary operator like so:

```
ComTypes comType = ...;
var title = comType == ComTypes.Call ? "Make a Call" : 
    comType == ComTypes.Email ? "Send an Email" : 
    /* ComTypes.SMS */ "Send a Text";
```

What i would like is to get a cleaner more concise format with a new operator for enumerations...  Something like the following:

```
ComTypes comType = ...;
var title = comType ? 
    .Call: "Make a Call", 
    .Email: "Send an Email", 
    .SMS|default: "Send a Text";
```

So I guess my starter questions are:

1. Can I create a custom operator and use it in parallel with normal C# compiler?
2. Assuming I can create the operator, can I use the "?" as the operator for enumerations even though it is being used by the standard Ternary Op for Boolean values?
3. I know I can go to Google for this one, but if anyone has any recommendations on good compiler creation articles that would be great.

**--EDIT--**

I just want to get this up here... I know that it wouldn't be practical if this were stopping me from doing development...  I know how to achieve this several other ways...  What i want here is some help understanding my starting points for achieving what I have outlined...  Merely for the pleasure of trying to code it out and learn more about the framework I use from day to day.

Comment: I feel your pain with that. I miss such short expressions available in other languages. But I also feel that your attempt is simply not worth it, except for the amusement granted if you succeeded. Instead of building such operator just to shorten a few expressions, do it smart: drop the "expression" altogether, as it is a CONSTANT key-value mapping, and build a dictionary key:enum/value:string and just use it to lookup in a simple result=dict[myenumval] way. Easier, faster, more coherent, easier to edit. DRY.

Comment: `switch` is the closest you're going to get without inconveniencing yourself too much. If you write your own compiler, code portability gets thrown out the window since no one else will have your compiler and the regular C# compiler will show a bunch of errors.

Comment: Ok, I understood you want the amusement:) see my post.

Comment: " get a cleaner more concise format with a new operator"  Introducing a new operator into a well established language with a compiler "extension" will never be clean or concise.  It will just make it impossible for other people to read your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so as to the how: I cannot give you any exact answer, but the case is almost impossible in the way you have stated it.

The CODE compiler is completely.. hm.. sealed. It is monolithic, with some minor extension points (see ExtensionMethods and the LINQ sublangauge). If you ever actually find how the LINQ sublanguage plugin is attached to the compiler, drop me a note, pretty I please. I doubt it, I believe LINQ syntax is hardcoded into the compiler ,but maybe I'm wrong.

But if I'm not wrong - then adding an operator is completely impossible, at least in the way you view it. There are other ways of course.

See the XAML or ASPX files, or RESX? How they are processed by the compiler, hm? Building a project is a multistep process. Parsing the XAML/ASPX/RESX files is before C#-code-compiling. That files are read, a tool generates .g.cs /.Designer.cs /aspx.cs/.resx.cs files that are then added to the compilation set, and the XAML/ASPX/RESX are not actually compiled by the C# compiler.

What does it mean? It means that you could change the extension of your files to, for example, .blargh, then write a plugin like XAML/ASPX/RESX parser/generator to preprocess the .blargh into .cs, and voila. In the .blargh you have your own extra syntax goodies, translated to verbose C# which is then compiled by normal C# compiler.

But note that while it would actually work very well, changing the file extension would most surely unbind the Intellisense and other csharpy IDE utilities and I bet you do not want to rewrite them almost from scratch for your pretty new code file extension - actually, pretty new languge..

But wait, there is more and it is way simpler!

You do not even need the .blargh file class. The project structure is build upon MSBuild build system. Somewhere on your drive there is a bunch of XML scripts that describe every single step that the build system does during "solution build" or "project build". They are **editable** and even better, they are **extensible**. You are able to write a plugin to the build system and inject it in between virtually any existing step of the build process.

Imagine the simplicity: you write a simple search-replace utility that loads a C# file with your extra markup, processes it, and writes back "expanded", translated to normal C#. You can inject it before "compile" phase and you are done with your problem.

One thing to remember: you cannot OVERWRITE the ORIGINAL file. It would be not wise, as it would mean that everything you briefly wrote with yout new operators - would be autoexpanded and replaced upon the build - permanently. :) You will want to write the expanded to some temporary file, add that file to the current temporary compilation file set under build (and also remove the original file, as it is not neeeded anymore).

You should notice that this is again exactly what happens with XAML/RESX/.. files and .g.cs/.resx.cs/... temporaries. It is because this is the normal way of handling such cases in the VS/MSBuild system :) If you do not want to build new language support, you translate between your and some known language, and then add it as a **preprocesing** step. Thats all.

Comment: If you need more poiinters, ask (me?) further. But I'm sure that you will find everything you need if only you search for topics on the MSBuild and on "how to add a custom MSBuild tasks to .csproj" :)

Comment: Fantastic set of recommended solutions!

Answer (score 3):

why don't you  want use just switch?

```
string title = "";

switch (comType)
{
  case (ComTypes.Call):
    title = "Make a Call";
    break;
  case (ComTypes.Email):
    title = "Send an Email";
    break; 
  case (ComTypes.SMS):
    title = "Send a Text";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Obviously I could use a switch statement, some reasons I am curious are for doe readability and to cut down lines of code...  In the end I am more curious about how I could achieve that...  

Its about learning more on how I can do things like that.  You know that curiosity most of us developers have...  I just want to learn how I could write my own shortcuts

Comment: @MichaelGearhardt ...and it's obviously that you don't want to use KeyValuePair or Dictionary or Tuple[] or anything else for this.. so just update your question that you don't want to use any obvious solutions and give the list of them.

Comment: @MichaelGearhardt it's fine. nobody knows what is obvious for you and what is not while you don't say about this.

Comment: Good answer, but for a *devils-advocate* argument (in response to your -1 on my post regarding changes to the enum definition) I would recommend you explicitly define a `case (ComTypes.SMS)` and not use the `default` since changes to the enum definition could likewise cause the "magic" to quit working.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments to other answers, it looks like you want to do this as a learning exercise and not something that you would use in production code, so while there are several very good answers that I would recommend for any other case, here's are a few ways you would do it via a custom compiler:

- Write an application that's run pre-build that scans all your C# files for your custom syntax and replaces it with a switch statement before feeding it into the compiler.
- Write your own full C# compiler with your custom syntax built into it. (.NET C# compiler isn't open source AFAIK)
- Modify [Mono's compiler](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs) to include your new syntax. This is probably the easiest solution and you'll still learn a lot about how C# gets compiled down to CIL and then JITted.

Also note that your syntax requires you to look very far ahead in the lexical stream to determine whether you're looking at a ternary operator or your new operator.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you want to use the enum as a hash table.  Why not just use a hash table instead.

```
Dictionary<ComTypes,String>
```

Comment: Again, this is not about the other possible solutions... I have working code, and can achieve what I need without problem...  This is about how I can go about achieving what I laid out in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator is not an overloadable operator in C#.

That being said, I would recommend the concise:

```
public enum ComTypes { Call = 0, Email = 1, SMS = 2 };
public readonly string[] ComTitles = 
     { "Make a Call", "Send an Email", "Send a Text" };
```

And later in code you could just use

```
ComTitles[comType]
```

Comment: -1 for the "magic" connection between the enum and titles array.

Comment: when someone will change the order of ComTitles array he/she will have to remember about the right index for using it with ComTypes enum. it's the same for the enum. this is a very bad approach to rely on indexes is such cases.

Comment: @BurundukXP, i mostly agree from a *best practices* point of view; however, if the enum and array were wrapped up in a class definition (the array being private), and a public property to handle the indexing, this is a perfectly usable approach.

Comment: To escape the magic, we have a `Dictionary<K,V>` class in the BCL. Why do you want to fallback to "enum is int" battle?